# How to add Data to a multi-column, data-bound ListView in WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, listview, c#-4.0

How do I add data to a multi-column data bound ListView in WPF?

Here's the code for the ListView

```
<ListView Height="263" Margin="12,29,12,0" Name="Tasks_ListView" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="91" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CourseName}"  Header="Class Name" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="275" Header="Assignment Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding AssignmentName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="110" Header="Due Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Due_Date}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="184" Header="Unit" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Unit}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I tried googling it for quite awhile and I haven't come up with any working results

Here is the Data I want to add:

```
foreach (Course Courses in CurrentUser.Course)
            {
                foreach (Assignment SelectedAssignment in Courses.CurrentUnit.Assignments)
                {
                    ListViewItem CourseName = new ListViewItem();
                    ListViewItem AssignmentName = new ListViewItem();
                    ListViewItem DueDate = new ListViewItem();
                    ListViewItem UnitName = new ListViewItem();
                    CourseName.Name = Courses.Name;
                    AssignmentName.Name = SelectedAssignment.Name;
                    DueDate.Name = SelectedAssignment.Due_Date.ToString();
                    UnitName.Name = Courses.CurrentUnit.Name;
                    Tasks_ListView.Items.Add();
                }
            }
```

How would I add the ListViewItem's in their respected categories per line?

Comment: what is your data context?  What isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

With the updated question, here's an updated answer.

I don't think you can do what your asking ("how I would add the ListViewItems on one line in their respective categories"). The ListView only holds a single collection of items, not one collection per column. If you want to use the ListView with data binding, you should prepare your data in a single collection of assignments, each one with at least the properties name, course name, due date and unit. And finally bind your ListView's ItemsSource property to your collection of assignments.

Comment: I updated the question, I would just like to know how I would add the ListViewItems on one line in their respective categories